# WordPress: Thumbnail e permalink errados sendo exibidos

Tags: wordpress

Estou com problemas para fazer com que o thumbnail (imagem destacada) e o permalink do post mais recente sejam exibidos na home do meu blog. Eu fiz o seguinte código:

```
<?php
     $posts_noticias = get_noticias_posts();
     $destacado = array_shift($posts_noticias);
?>
<div id="noticia_destacada">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(array(495, 368, true)); ?>
        <span class="data_noticia"><?php echo $destacado->post_date ?></span>
        <h3 class="title_destacada"><?php echo $destacado->post_title ?></h3>
        <?php echo $destacado->post_excerpt ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

O código da função get_noticias_posts() é o seguinte:

```
function get_noticias_posts($number = 5){
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => $number,
    'offset'           => 0,
    'category'         => get_cat_ID( 'noticias' ),
    'orderby'          => 'post_date',
    'order'            => 'DESC',
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'post_status'      => 'publish',
    'suppress_filters' => true );

    $posts_array = get_posts( $args );

    return $posts_array;
}
```

Porém, a imagem exibida e o permalink que coloquei nela não são do último post e sim de um post mais antigo, de dias atrás. A data, título e excerto do post mais recente aparecem normalmente.

Não consigo perceber em que parte do código eu errei. Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Será que não deveria usar a mesma instrução para thumbnail que usou para `post_date` e `post_title` tipo: `<?php echo $destacado->the_post_thumbnail(array(495, 368, true)); ?>`

Comment: @marcosvinicius Infelizmente deu erro fatal aqui nos meus testes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um pouco complicado de dizer, pois não tem muitos detalhes e nem exatamente o que essa função `get_noticias_posts()` faz e como retorna os valores.
Mas olhando pelos valores das outras coisas que você imprimiu parece que esta retornando um objeto `WP_Post`, sendo assim você pode fazer desta forma:

```php
<div id="noticia_destacada">
    <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink( $destacado->ID ); ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $destacado->ID, array( 495, 368, true ) ); ?>
        <span class="data_noticia"><?php echo $destacado->post_date; ?></span>
        <h3 class="title_destacada"><?php echo $destacado->post_title; ?></h3>
        <?php echo $destacado->post_excerpt; ?>
    </a>
</div>
```

Basta usar o [`get_the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) que ele recebe o parâmetro para o ID do post, caso o contrário ele vai pegar do loop do WordPress.
E no seu caso o loop é personalizado e você não esta configurando a variável global `$post`, então o melhor é fazer assim pegando pelo ID.

Comment: Desculpe pela falta de informações. Vou acrescentar o código da função na pergunta.

De qualquer forma eu editei o código seguindo sua orientação. Vou verificar no servidor se o problema se resolveu e dar uma resposta logo mais.

Comment: `<?php echo get_the_permalink($destacado->ID); ?>` isso estaria certo @Claudio Sanches?

Comment: @Claudio Sanches, obrigado novamente! O código agora exibe a thumbnail correta.

Comment: @marcosvinicius eu não tinha visto o `the_permalink()` obrigado por avisar. @giancarlo-silva acabei de arrumar ai permalink também ai.